# how can i resize font of div by resizing the div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, fonts, resize

can anyone please help me, how to resize font size by resize event of div using jquery ui plugin?

html :

```
<div>my testing data</div>
```

script :

```
$('div').resize(); //this function is called from resize plugin of ui jquery
```

i want to increase font size by resizing the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Darmen is right. But, you can simplify the code a little bit by using some of the method overloads. Like the constructor:

```
$('#dialog').resizable({
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        ui.element.css({'font-size':'20px'});
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, it's clear. I wanted to add that as a comment or your answer; but I can't find the link to do that. The only options I see below your answer are "link" and "flag".

Comment: its working fine, i have just make little change in it

$('#dialog').resizable({

resize: function(event, ui) {
var height1 = parseInt(ui.element.css('height'));
ui.element.css({'font-size': height1+'px'});
}

});

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog), you can do something like this:

```
$("#dialog").bind('resize', function(event, ui){
   var height = $(this).dialog('option', 'height');
   $(this).css('font-size', height);
});
```

Consider your `div` has an`id="dialog"`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the height again accessing 'option' you can use the ui object, it will give you start size, end size and location too.

```
* ui.helper - a jQuery object containing the helper element
* ui.originalPosition - {top, left} before resizing started
* ui.originalSize - {width, height} before resizing started
* ui.position - {top, left} current position
* ui.size - {width, height} current size
```